# For an array of objects I want to find the frequency of different values for one and the same property but want to write specific counts to each item

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, reduce

I have an array of object with keys and values but sometimes different values to a specific key. I want to find the frequency of different values for one and the same property name. A sample data structure might look like this ...

```js
var input = [{
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Capabilities",
  "assessment_field": "channel_availability",
  "assessment_field_values": "Yes",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Capabilities",
  "assessment_field": "channel_availability",
  "assessment_field_values": "No",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Awareness",
  "assessment_field": "Monthly_price_visibility",
  "assessment_field_values": "Lead on all comms",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Awareness",
  "assessment_field": "Monthly_price_visibility",
  "assessment_field_values": "In buyflow marketing",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Awareness",
  "assessment_field": "Monthly_price_visibility",
  "assessment_field_values": "Financing as option at checkout",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}];
```

Having found all the property value specific counts, I want to change each original array item which relates to a specific counting in such a way, that it will feature an additional `Count` field for each relevant property and value count.

Counting the frequency of different values for the following item properties ... `DPM`, `Tracking_Block` and `assessment_field` ... the original sample data from above then would change to ...

```js
[{
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Capabilities",
  "assessment_field": "channel_availability",
  "assessment_field_values": "Yes",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
  "DPM_Count": 5,
  "Tracking_Block_Count": 2,
  "assessment_field_Count": 2,
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Capabilities",
  "assessment_field": "channel_availability",
  "assessment_field_values": "No",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
  "DPM_Count": 5,
  "Tracking_Block_Count": 2,
  "assessment_field_Count": 2,
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Awareness",
  "assessment_field": "Monthly_price_visibility",
  "assessment_field_values": "Lead on all comms",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
  "DPM_Count": 5,
  "Tracking_Block_Count": 3,
  "assessment_field_Count": 3,
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Awareness",
  "assessment_field": "Monthly_price_visibility",
  "assessment_field_values": "In buyflow marketing",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
  "DPM_Count": 5,
  "Tracking_Block_Count": 3,
  "assessment_field_Count": 3,
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Awareness",
  "assessment_field": "Monthly_price_visibility",
  "assessment_field_values": "Financing as option at checkout",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
  "DPM_Count": 5,
  "Tracking_Block_Count": 3,
  "assessment_field_Count": 3,
}]
```

Below is the code I attempted in order to group and count.

```js
const result = Object.values(input.reduce( (acc,i) => {
    const key = i.DPM+ i. Tracking_Block + i. assessment_field;
    if(!acc[key])
       acc[key] = {...i, assessment_field_values: [i. assessment_field_values] }
    else
       acc[key]. assessment_field_values.push(i. assessment_field_values);
    return acc;
 },{}));
```

Comment: Your output doesn't make much sense. You have two entries with the same key `color`, also `categoryCount` seems to always be `2` and one can wonder why you have an array containing n times the same string.

Comment: what is `Tracking_Block_Count` counting?

Comment: Number of Tracking_Block in an object

Comment: is the wanted result the real result from the given data? please add what counts and why. for example `DMP` has five values, but all are the same. `Tracking_Block` has 5 values but only two different ones. how do you get one in the result, it is always one, because of the same group. do i miss something?

Comment: I want to find out the count of the DPM properties in the list of array as well Tracking Block

Comment: yes, i want it too, but what to count?

Comment: @ballic ... does my last change to your question actually reflect your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good approach was to identify tasks and implement them separately.

Thus, one first wants to figure out how often the same value of one or more property/ies do/es occur.

This can be solved generically by a configurable [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works) task which reads and processes a property list and does count all the properties' values.

```js
function collectEntryCounts(config, item) {
  const { propertyList, counts } = config;

  // custom list of property names whose frequencies have to be counted.
  propertyList.forEach(propertyName => {

    // if the currently processed item features
    // one of the specified property names ...
    if (propertyName in item) {

      // ... get the property name specific count index
      // or create it in case it does not yet exist and ...
      const countIndex = counts[propertyName] || (counts[propertyName] = {});

      // ... get the current array item's property value ... 
      const propertyValue = item[propertyName];

      // ... which will be used as key for the property value specific count.
      if (propertyValue in countIndex) {

        countIndex[propertyValue]++;
      } else {
        countIndex[propertyValue] = 1;
      }
    }
  });

  return config;
}

var input = [{
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Capabilities",
  "assessment_field": "channel_availability",
  "assessment_field_values": "Yes",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Capabilities",
  "assessment_field": "channel_availability",
  "assessment_field_values": "No",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Awareness",
  "assessment_field": "Monthly_price_visibility",
  "assessment_field_values": "Lead on all comms",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Awareness",
  "assessment_field": "Monthly_price_visibility",
  "assessment_field_values": "In buyflow marketing",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Awareness",
  "assessment_field": "Monthly_price_visibility",
  "assessment_field_values": "Financing as option at checkout",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}];

console.log(
  'property value counts index ...',
  input.reduce(collectEntryCounts, {

    propertyList: ['DPM', 'Tracking_Block', 'assessment_field'],
    counts: {},

  }).counts
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Within a second step one now can alter/mutate each item of the original array by adding the key-value specific counts to it.

This too, will be done by a generic implementation like ... `addEntryCountsFromBoundConfig` ... which is an [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#syntax) task with a configuration bound to it as the [`forEach`'s `thisArgs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#parameters) argument.

The config object itself is the result of the `reduce` task from running `collectEntryCounts`  before.

```js
function collectEntryCounts(config, item) {
  const { propertyList, counts } = config;

  // custom list of property names whose frequencies have to be counted.
  propertyList.forEach(propertyName => {

    // if the currently processed item features
    // one of the specified property names ...
    if (propertyName in item) {

      // ... get the property name specific count index
      // or create it in case it does not yet exist and ...
      const countIndex = counts[propertyName] || (counts[propertyName] = {});

      // ... get the current array item's property value ... 
      const propertyValue = item[propertyName];

      // ... which will be used as key for the property value specific count.
      if (propertyValue in countIndex) {

        countIndex[propertyValue]++;
      } else {
        countIndex[propertyValue] = 1;
      }
    }
  });

  return config;
}

function addEntryCountsFromBoundConfig(item) {
  const { propertyList, counts } = this; // `this` equals the bound config.

  propertyList.forEach(propertyName => {

    // if the currently processed item features one of the specified property
    // names and if the property name specific count index does exist too ...
    if ((propertyName in item) && counts[propertyName]) {

      // ... assign this count index from the bound config-properties and ...
      const countIndex = counts[propertyName];

      // ... do mutate the currently processed item by creating
      // the property specific count field and assigning its value.
      item[propertyName + '_Count'] = countIndex[item[propertyName]];
    }
  });
} 

var input = [{
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Capabilities",
  "assessment_field": "channel_availability",
  "assessment_field_values": "Yes",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Capabilities",
  "assessment_field": "channel_availability",
  "assessment_field_values": "No",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Awareness",
  "assessment_field": "Monthly_price_visibility",
  "assessment_field_values": "Lead on all comms",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Awareness",
  "assessment_field": "Monthly_price_visibility",
  "assessment_field_values": "In buyflow marketing",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}, {
  "DPM": "Financing",
  "Tracking_Block": "Awareness",
  "assessment_field": "Monthly_price_visibility",
  "assessment_field_values": "Financing as option at checkout",
  "Field_Type": "Dropdown",
}];

input.forEach(
  // the callback function.
  addEntryCountsFromBoundConfig,

  // the this context bound to the above callback.
  input.reduce(collectEntryCounts, {
    propertyList: ['DPM', 'Tracking_Block', 'assessment_field'],
    counts: {},
  })
);
console.log('mutated `input` array ...', input);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @NinaScholz ... I think not only the OP might take something from it, thus I do not consider it to be *"Perlen vor die ..."*. Außerdem war mir gerad' fad.

Comment: yes I was looking for something like this,Thank you for helping me out

Comment: @ballic ... ok are there any questions left then regarding the above approach?

Comment: @PeterSeliger I am currently pursuing graduation if you dont mind can you explain more in detailed? Extremely sorry for this

Comment: @ballic ...The approach already got split into two tasks with explanations what each task is supposed to achieve. Short introductions and links to MDN's(Mozilla Developer Network) documentation have been provided as well. Just explain at which point(s) you could not follow or got stuck.

Comment: sorry I am very new to Stackoverflow i dint know to mark accpeted/sovled